# Springboot jpa, get rows with specific fields using two joins

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have entities :`Student`, `Class`, `Room`.

`student M-M class`, `student M-M rooms`, thus two junction tables. Now I want to get all `students` assigned to class `X` and room `Y`. Thus I've made:

```
@Query("SELECT s from Student s INNER JOIN s.classes c INNER JOIN s.rooms r WHERE c.id LIKE ?1 AND r.id LIKE ?2")
Page<Student> findAllInClassAndRoom(final Long classId, final Long roomId, final Pageable pageable);
```

But it gives me wrong results. Is there an error in my query ?

Comment: I think you should not use `LIKE` when searching by id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error in your query is the LIKE statement. Just change the equal sign "=". As below:

```
@Query("SELECT s from Student s INNER JOIN s.classes c INNER JOIN s.rooms r WHERE c.id = ?1 AND r.id = ?2")
Page<Student> findAllInClassAndRoom(final Long classId, final Long roomId, final Pageable pageable);
```

The LIKE statement allows a greater mass of data. Because it would allow any Room or Class that part of the code is the id entered as a parameter.
[LIKE statement specification](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13946_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_like)